# Tell Dired to ignore file-at-point when invoking `ido-find-file` (`C-x C-f` in Ido mode)

Tags: dired, ido, find-file

I have discovered that a recent update to some of my emacs packages have caused `C-x C-f` while on a dired file to perform some operation on the entire file before prompting me for other files/directories.

I know that I need to track down what is causing this issue, but in the meantime, **is there a way I can tell dired to ignore the current file-at-point when invoking `C-x C-f` in a dired buffer?**

I frequently invoke this in a dired buffer containing videos around 500mb-1gb, and even with `(setq debug-on-quit t)` I cannot interrupt the process after hitting `C-x C-f`, emacs simply spins at 100% cpu for a few minutes until the ido prompt comes up.

Comment: Clarify, please: to what command is `C-x C-f` bound?

Comment: @Dan `C-x C-f` is bound to `find-file`

Comment: I believe he wants to disable the `ffap` (find file at point) when doing `find-file` in `dired`.

Comment: The default `find-file` behavior does not use `ffap`. Also, `ffap` (or `ido-use-filename-at-point`) wouldn't be affected by the size of the files. Sounds like some other issue here, with non-default configuration. @LeeH, can you reproduce this problem if you start emacs with `-Q`?

Comment: Oh -- you do mentioned `ido` in your question above. So for one thing, I assume `C-x C-f` is bound to `ido-find-file` rather than `find-file`? I do have some configuration to prevent ido from using the filename at point as the default, which I'll add as an answer below. Still doesn't explain your CPU spin, though.

Comment: If `debug-on-quit` doesn't work, the next thing to try is `kill -USR2 <emacspid>`.  That should hopefully give you a backtrace.

Comment: I don't know what is causing this, but I was just able to confirm the issue with a 3.15gb ISO file.  In my case this was on Win7 on a network share (mapped drive).  `C-x C-f` bound to `ido-find-file` and `ido-use-filename-at-point` as `t`.  Changing it to `nil` removed the delay.

Comment: @JonathanLeech-Pepin Interesting, so I guess file size is a factor after all. In that case my answer below might be helpful. Another thing to play with might be `ido-max-directory-size`, which can disable ido completion in large directories.

Comment: @JonathanLeech-Pepin could you file a bug for that?

Comment: Thanks for the debugging tips and assistance everyone. It was indeed `ido-use-filename-at-point`/`ido-use-url-at-point`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using `ido-find-file` and have configured ido to use the filename at point (e.g. you have `ido-use-filename-at-point` set to `t` or `'guess`), you can prevent ido from using the name at point from a dired buffer with a hook:

```
(defun my/ido-ignore-file-at-point ()
  "Disable ido-use-filename-at-point for the current buffer."
  (when (bound-and-true-p ido-use-filename-at-point)
    (setq-local ido-use-filename-at-point nil)))

(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook #'my/ido-ignore-file-at-point)))
```

If you never want ido to use the name at point, set `ido-use-filename-at-point` to nil. I believe that is the default behavior though, so you may have customized it at some point.

If you experience issues with ido completion in large directories you may also want to customize `ido-max-directory-size`.